# What is making my search bar be in the center?

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I'm trying to make my search bar go above my menu, but it seems to be in the center of the page. I'm not sure what's forcing it down below my menu bar div, but I suspect it's something in the CSS because the search bar is technically on the same row as where the logo should be going. I've divided the row into two columns, one a small col-sm-3, and the other a width of 9.

so I want it to look like this: [image]

But it currently looks like this:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<!--Fixed Search Bar-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>Insert Logo</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="search">
                        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
                        <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--End of Fixed Search Bar-->


    <!--Menu-->
    <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i> Messages</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i> Notifications</span></a></li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> My Account</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings & Preferences</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Billing & Subscriptions</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i> Paid Features & Power Profile</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Searching & Matching</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Start a Company Page</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i> Log-Out</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#"><span>Need Help?</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Submit a Request</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Dispute a Review</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!--End of Menu-->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    /*search bar*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body{
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;  
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.wrap{
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*end of search bar*/



/* menu bar*/
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #0b3c5d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #115f94), color-stop(100%, #0b3c5d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #328cc1;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #0b3c5d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #115f94), color-stop(100%, #0b3c5d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #328cc1;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #031019;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #031019;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #031019;
  background: #082d46;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0f517d), color-stop(100%, #082d46));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #328cc1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #53a3d3;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #286f98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #286f98;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #53a3d3;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #226084;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* end of menu bar*/
```

Comment: What css-framework are you using?

Comment: It's your use of absolute positioning with `.wrap`. I don't see why you even need the `.wrap` element. What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

remove wrap class and from search class width:100%

and

```
.searchTerm {
      width: 100%;
      border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 38px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      outline: none;
      color: #9DBFAF;
    }

    .searchButton {
      position: absolute;  
      right: 0px;
      top:0px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 36px;
      border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
      background: #00B4CC;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```css
/*search bar*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body{
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.search {
  position: relative
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 0px;
  top:0px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*end of search bar*/



/* menu bar*/
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #0b3c5d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #115f94), color-stop(100%, #0b3c5d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #328cc1;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #0b3c5d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #115f94), color-stop(100%, #0b3c5d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #115f94 0%, #0b3c5d 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #328cc1;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #031019;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #031019;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #031019;
  background: #082d46;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0f517d), color-stop(100%, #082d46));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0f517d 0%, #082d46 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #328cc1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #53a3d3;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #286f98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #286f98;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #53a3d3;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #226084;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Fixed Search Bar-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>Insert Logo</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="search">
                        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
                        <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--End of Fixed Search Bar-->


    <!--Menu-->
    <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i> Messages</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i> Notifications</span></a></li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> My Account</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings & Preferences</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Billing & Subscriptions</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i> Paid Features & Power Profile</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Searching & Matching</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Start a Company Page</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i> Log-Out</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#"><span>Need Help?</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Submit a Request</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Dispute a Review</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!--End of Menu-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrap class in the div above the div containing you search class is causing this issue.

Change

```
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
                    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

to

```
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
                    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: Thanks! now it's above, but very long, not fitting within the col-sm-9 parameters, even extending past the menu bar.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? I can't see col-sm-9 in your CSS, it's normally used within bootstrap however I can't see bootstrap being tagged?

Comment: How do I tag bootstrap to use their grid form? I didn't realize I had to do that when building an html page from scratch.

Comment: No problem. Normal CSS and HTML doesn't understand col-sm-3. Unless you are also using bootstrap. See here for help adding bootstrap to your code. http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download, the easiest way is to add the CDN links in your HTML file.

Comment: And I add those three blocks of code in my <head> like linking to a CSS file?

Comment: Add the minified CSS link to the head. The theme is optional and lastly add the link to the javascript file to the bottom of your HTML file just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Note: You can change the width of the search bar and the top size...just play with it.

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/zt6u1q1o/2/)** [update]

**I'm not sure what's forcing it down below my menu bar:**

What is forcing is your `.wrap` class with this rules:

```
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Negative ... why? Can someone explain to me?